# Execute android activity function on another class of java dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Hi I am new to android were I have create the activity and it's works fine and now I need to create dynamically to call activity function. So on my project data are fetch from server side so I have make common function for all activity but data are come in json so parsing the json which I have wrote the function on activity so it's work fine but I will pass activity name as well as method of the respective function so it should load dynamically and give the result but it not works on it see below the code:

```
((MainActivity) activity).parseJsonResponse(result);
```

the above code it works fine

for dynamically I have work this code which not works for

```
 ClassLoader myClassLoader=ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
 String classNameToBeLoaded = "MainActivity";
 Class myClass = Class.forName("com.example.iripl_09.helloworld." + classNameToBeLoaded);
 Object whatInstance = myClass.newInstance();
 String methodParameter = result;
 Method myMethod = myClass.getMethod("parseJsonResponse",new Class[] { String.class });
 myMethod.invoke(whatInstance, new Object[] { methodParameter });
```

So it give error:

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Is there any method to call MainActivity function it there or not

Answer (score 1):

Most of the Activity functions/methods which act as entry point to the class are 'overriden'. Therefore it is not a good practice to call those via direct function call or via reflection.

Most of such cases result in the same error. Even if you might not get this error, you may disrupt the normal activity flow defined by Android system.

Having said that, to answer the question, it is good practice to avoid keeping the generic methods in activity, which need to be called by other classes. Such methods should be kept in the classes such as Utility/Toolkit etc which are then kept common across the application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can instantiate activities yourself (you have to do it through Intent). In my opinion this parseJsonResponse method should reside in another class so you don't have to instantiate an activity (which is very expensive)  just to parse your JSON.

It would be better to have a helper class in which you could factorize the code for JSON parsing and share between application components.

Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

Make a `BaseActivity extends Activity` and then make all your other activities `extend BaseActivity` so that every one of your Activities will have the `parseJson()` or `super.parseJson()` method instead of calling someone elses method?

Or, why not keep that method in a Util class? Calling `otherActivity.parseJson()` is somewhat dangerous due to activities dying/being garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

As @darthvading said, You can create a separate class say ParseUtils with some static method.

```
public class ParseUtil {
    public static List<YourClassName> parse(){
        List<YourClassName> items;
        // Your logic to parse the strings
        return items;
    }
}
```

To Parse the data from your Activity, you'll have to call

```
List<YourClassName> items = ParseUtil.parse(yourString);
```

Once you done with the parsing, you can display the data within the same activity or you can pass the data to the other activity using [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) or [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) Interface.